# Does ListNodes behave differently inside a loop? java

Tags: java, list, loops, linked-list

I saw this solution of Merging Two Sorted Lists... i didn't quite understand how it works:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode mergeTwoLists(ListNode list1, ListNode list2) {
        if (list1==null && list2==null)
        return null;
       

      ListNode dummy= new ListNode(-1);
      ListNode result = dummy;
       while (list1!=null && list2!=null){
          if (list1.val<=list2.val){
              result.next = list1;
          list1=list1.next;
          }
         else {
               result.next=list2;
          list2=list2.next;         
          }
           result=result.next;
         }
            if (list1==null){
                result.next = list2;
                else if (list2==null){
                result.next = list1;
                

     
     return dummy.next;
    }
    }
```

Why when assigning  `result.next=list2;` or  `result.next=list1;` in the loop, it only takes the first node from list2 and list1. But when i did the same thing outside the loop

```
  if (list1==null){
                result.next = list2;
                else if (list2==null){
                result.next = list1;
```

instead of assigning the first value, it assigned what left of the list. How does this work i don't understand

Help me understand what a ListNode Actually is, and how this code works.

Comment: why do you think it "only takes the first node"? It takes the whole remainder of the list, but the `next` link will (eventually) be changed in the next iteration or by the `if (list1 == null) ....` statement after the loop

Comment: try the [Java Visualizer](https://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/java_visualize/)

Comment: Is this for [LeetCode 21](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/) ?

Comment: One approach is to copy the solution to your machine, add code for `ListNode` , and code a test driver. You could then run the program in a debugger: Set an early breakpoint, and then run the program one-step-at-a-time.

Comment: Thanks you so much  " 
Old Dog Programmer" this helped but not as much

Comment: I didn't completely understand how, when doing result = result.next;, the node 'result' (which doesn't exist at this point) was/will be moved to the dummy ListNode, since 'result' doesn't exist now, only 'result.next' and beyond.

Comment: ^ That is a different question. Please focus your question on one question only, and provide a simple input example inside your question that you have tested with. Pinpoint exactly what you find during stepping through the code (with a debugger) and at which stage you have a question about it.

Comment: Pretend you are a computer. Your memory is paper and pen. Draw it out. Use a circle to represent a `Node`. Write the `int` value inside the circle. Represent each `next` by drawing an arrow to the node to which it points. A `null` can be represented with a circle with an `X`.  At each step, show a change by making a new drawing of `list1`, `list2`, `result`, or `dummy`, and cross off the previous version.